# My JDL file cannot be imported even though it contains no errors

Tags: jhipster

I've created my JDL file properly but when I try to import it into my JHipster project, the command prompt shows me this error:

```
Error: The JDL object and the database type are both mandatory.
Error while parsing applications and entities from the JDL Error: The JDL object and the database type are both mandatory.
```

Comment: I'm using JHipster V6.5.1

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by importing the JDL file from my JHipster application’s root folder.